# Regular expression : I need to retrieve a part of a string into a string

Tags: apex, regular-expressions

I have a string that could be of this kind, for example :

> String text = 'test AZ123AZ testtesttest';

I need to retrive this part of the string :

> AZ123AZ

So for now I have something like this in my apex code :

```
String regexTest ='[A-Z]{2}[0-9]{3}[A-Z]{2}';
Matcher matcher =Pattern.compile(regexTest ).matcher(text);
Boolean result = matcher.find();
```

The boolean result gives me true if the regex type is in a string so it's ok, but I need to retrive the value of the regex to put it into another string (only this part of the string `text` is important for me)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can iterate over matching segments of your text using `matcher.group()`:

```
while (matcher.find()) {
    System.debug(matcher.group());
}
```

If you know you only have one match, or only want the first match, you can just call `matcher.group()` directly without using a loop.